# How to use delay functions in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

I want to send a character with Bluetooth. The code works perfectly when there is only a single character.But I want to use a delay function between the two codes. 
I want to enter any number with EditText and the app will take that number and do EditText/44. That is what I want to wait between 2 codes

**Finally work.. Thanks guys. :)**

I moved a,b,c inside setOnClick.. ;

```
kileri = (Button) findViewById(R.id.kileri);
final EditText value1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textkont);
assert value1 != null;
value1.setText("0");


btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
checkBTState();

kileri.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int a = Integer.parseInt(value1.getText().toString());
            int b = a / 44;
            int c = b * 1000;

            sendData("F");

            try {
                Thread.sleep(c);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: "I try lots of things but i failure." Please show what you have tried, and describe the way in which they didn't work.

Comment: Are you entering a value greater than or equal to 44 into `value1`?

Comment: @AndyTurner yes I enter 100 or 200. I have a problem with Edittext. App cant take number from that. When I write a number instead of 'c' most of delay function is work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 try {
       //set time in mili
        Thread.sleep(3000);

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**edited as your code**

```
 kileri.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendData("F");
            try {
                //set time in mili
                Thread.sleep(3000);

            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            sendData("S");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Where I write sendData("S"); ?

Comment: after try catch  u can write sendData("S");

Comment: Thanks i will try that.

Comment: @R.SahinAltunbas  3000 is equal to 3 Second u can set your time like 100/200/300 mili second as per your requirment

Comment: If i write a number like 3000 it work , but when i write 'c' didn't work. I want to wait Edittext/44 .

Comment: @R.SahinAltunbas first of all check the value of c maybe it c value is Zero(0)

Comment: I enter a integer on Edittext. I write 500 but it didn't work. Can you check my code ?

Comment: I think I have a problem with Edittext. When I write a number instead of 'c' most of delay function is work.

Comment: You shouldn't ever sleep on the UI or main thread as you would cause an AAR.

Answer (score 14):

You can use handler

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //do something
            }
        }, 2000 );//time in milisecond
```

Comment: this is preferred way  for doing `Handler` is designed for that

Comment: it send character without wait too.

Comment: increase time delay say 15 seconds or 20 sec

Comment: If i write a number like 3000 it work , but when i write 'c' didn't work. I want to wait Edittext/44 . I think I have a problem with Edittext.

Comment: Don't write 'c' let me know how many seconds you want to wait?

Comment: Not a constant. I want a different number with Edittext.

Answer (score 2):

Use handler like this:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // do something after 2s = 2000 miliseconds
        }
    }, 2000); //Time in milisecond
```

Comment: It work too but when i write 'c' instead of 2000 dont work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
kileri = (Button) findViewById(R.id.kileri);
final EditText value1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textkont);
assert value1 != null;
value1.setText("0");
final int a = Integer.parseInt(value1.getText().toString());
final int b = a/22;
final int c = b/2; // It will take a int from Edittext and do this operation on that.


btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
checkBTState();

kileri.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        sendData("F");
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                sendData("S");    
            }
        }, c);    
    }
});
```

Comment: I try this, But it send character without wait.

Answer (score 0):

just use `runOnUiThread` on button click and post `Handler` after time delay..

```
  Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendData("F");                   // send
            delay(2000);
        }
    });
```

**UPDATE**

delay()..

```
 public void delay(final int c){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(c);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            sendData("S");           //send
        }
    }, c);

}
```

Comment: I want to wait c seconds. It work when i write number but when i write 'c' instead of 2000 dont work.

Comment: it say " Variable 'delay' is never assigned" , "Variable 'c' is already defined in the scope" and "Method call expected" for delay(2000);

Comment: Finally worked. I move int a,b,c to inside setOnClick.. then i work. Thanks.

Comment: your welcome i am glad it worked...you can upvote if my answer helped you in any manner...so it can help other having same problem...

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to use Thread.Sleep because it stops execution of main thread if it is called in main thread execution.So,if we want to set delay we can use **CountDownTimer**.

In below snippet,we gave 2 seconds delay.So,after 2s onFinish() callback comes and we can have our operation there.

```
new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000) {
     public void onFinish() {
         
     }

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
          
 }.start();
}
```