# How can I delay multiple if conditional statements?

Tags: java, android

Is there a way I can delay an if statement for 1 sec before running the other if condition? I tried using a run-able handler for each statement but it crashes the app, I also used Thread.sleep(1000); but it just freezes the UI. How do I solve this?

This is how I first used the handler

```
final Handler Internet_handler = new Handler();
       final Runnable internet = new Runnable() {
           public void run() {if (EseCards_Slot1.isShown()) {
   EseCards_Slot1.performClick();
   bot_count++;
   Stop_Two_InstantPLay(); // stops 2 cards from playing i.e pick 2 and ride on
   botThinkdelay();// delays the if statement
}
           }
       };
       Internet_handler.postDelayed(internet, 1700);
```

```
if (EseCards_Slot1.isShown()) {
   EseCards_Slot1.performClick();
   bot_count++;
   Stop_Two_InstantPLay(); // stops 2 cards from playing i.e pick 2 and ride on
   botThinkdelay();// delays the if statement
}
if (EseCards_Slot2.isShown()) {
   EseCards_Slot2.performClick();
   bot_count++;
   Stop_Two_InstantPLay();
   botThinkdelay();
}
if (EseCards_Slot3.isShown()) {
   EseCards_Slot3.performClick();
   bot_count++;
   Stop_Two_InstantPLay();
   botThinkdelay();
}
if (EseCards_Slot4.isShown()) {
   EseCards_Slot4.performClick();
   bot_count++;
   Stop_Two_InstantPLay();
   botThinkdelay();
}
if (EseCards_Slot5.isShown()) {
   EseCards_Slot5.performClick();
   bot_count++;
   Stop_Two_InstantPLay();
   botThinkdelay();
}
if ((bot_count>0)&&(Ese_Turn_toPlay==true)) {
   Market.performClick();
   bot_count=0;
   botThinkdelay();
}
```

Comment: Use `Handler` or Kotlin coroutine `delay`.

Comment: i have already tried using handler and it crashes the app

Comment: It is very strange. I often tried `Handler`.

Comment: `final Handler Internet_handler = new Handler();
       final Runnable internet = new Runnable() {
           public void run() {if (EseCards_Slot1.isShown()) {
   EseCards_Slot1.performClick();
   bot_count++;
   Stop_Two_InstantPLay(); // stops 2 cards from playing i.e pick 2 and ride on
   botThinkdelay();// delays the if statement
}
     }
       };
       Internet_handler.postDelayed(internet, 1700);`

Comment: And what is an exception? Could you write the `Handler` in the question?

Comment: i have written it

Comment: You didn't show us exeption logs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call a method after a delay in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072173/how-to-call-a-method-after-a-delay-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you can use `Handler` (see [How to set delay in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874117/how-to-set-delay-in-android) or [How to use delay functions in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37323110/how-to-use-delay-functions-in-android-studio/37323343)). The code becomes ugly, but I know only a few solutions in Java for UI thread (`CountDownTimer`).

```
import android.os.Handler;

final Handler handler = new Handler();

if (EseCards_Slot1.isShown()) {
   EseCards_Slot1.performClick();
   bot_count++;
   Stop_Two_InstantPLay(); // stops 2 cards from playing i.e pick 2 and ride on
   handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (EseCards_Slot2.isShown()) {
               EseCards_Slot2.performClick();
               bot_count++;
               Stop_Two_InstantPLay();
               // Here comes the next Handler.
               // It would be better to divide if statements into methods
               // and run them inside each new handler.postDelayed.
            }
        }
    }, 1000);

}
```

You should remove all handlers after you close the screen.